# Load properties into application based on Weblogic managed server

Tags: soap, properties, configuration, jms, weblogic

I have this requirement - I have several managed servers running on my Weblogic (version 12.x). There are multiple machines as well.

Machine 1: Managed server 1, 2
Machine 2: Managed server 3, 4

I have a spring-boot based application (war) that is deployed across all managed servers. It has both an MDB (to read messages from JMS queue), and a SOAP Webservice.

The queue that it is reading messages from is however targeted/deployed only on a few managed servers - 1 and 3.

Now, I don't want my application to fail or start complaining when it doesn't find the queue on managed servers 2 and 4. Hence, I wish to load my MDB based on a property/configuration specific to managed server.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom System property to the server start parameters of server 2 and 4 in the admin console, ie: "-DignoreMDB=1" and read that using a *System.getProperty("ignoreMDB") != null* call. Note that you need to restart the nodemanager first and your managed servers second to get modification to the server start parameters active.